# How do you get the current Mac window position/origin programatically in swift

Tags: swift, macos

My thoughts are to put a function in the viewController, but when I call it, I just get 0 for both x and y instead of the window position, obviously I am messing up somewhere any ideas?

```
    class ViewController: NSViewController {
        
        func getCoordinate() {
            let x = self.view.frame.origin.x
            let y = self.view.frame.origin.y
            print (x)
            print (y)
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `view.window.frame`, rather than `view.frame`.

```
if let window = view.window {
    print(window.frame.origin)
} else {
    print("The view is not in a window yet!")
}
```

Remember to do this only after `view` is added to the window, such as in `viewDidAppear`.

The `view`'s frame is relative to `view`'s superview's origin, not the screen's origin. and it just so happens that in this case, `view` is positioned exactly at the origin of its superview (whatever view that is), hence (0, 0).